# How do I loop through all csv files in a directory, select a range of columns and combine to single csv?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, csv

I have a large number of CSV files in a specific directory. All have at least 41 columns with matching headers, but can be as wide as 200 columns. I need to grab just the first 40 columns and append them to create a single CSV with headers. I am relatively new and was trying to follow this example [How do I keep the first 200 lines of all the csv files in a directory using bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561600/how-do-i-keep-the-first-200-lines-of-all-the-csv-files-in-a-directory-using-bash) in combination with that one [Merging contents of multiple .csv files into single .csv file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293775/merging-contents-of-multiple-csv-files-into-single-csv-file). I am trying to limit it to a one-liner is possible and am thinking I need a combination of "cut" and "cat" commands. I unsuccessfully tried to run something like this:

```
$ for file in *.csv do cut -d ',' -f1-40 "$file" > "$file"; done
```

then

```
cat *csv > combined.csv
```

without any luck.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Check if [you truncated your files to zero size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/558773/108618). I hope you have backups.

Comment: I sure did @KamilMaciorowski. Thankfully I ran in a test directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple efficient concatenation of CSV files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234128/simple-efficient-concatenation-of-csv-files)

Comment: I see the shell gurus helped you out. I added a solution that uses a CSV-aware tool. Dependency on 3rd-party software, but much less shell for the tradeoff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to overwrite each file and to concatenate later, get `cut` to cut all the files and output the result into `combined.csv` directly.

You'll want to make sure `combined.csv` itself is not included in the list, or you could end up with an infinite loop filling up your filesystem.

```
(rm -f combined.csv && set ./*.csv && cut -d, -f1-40 "$@" > combined.csv)
```

Or (assuming GNU `xargs` or compatible):

```
(
  rm -f combined.csv &&
    set ./*.csv &&
    printf '%s\0' "$@" |
      xargs -r0 cut -d, -f1-40 > combined.csv
)
```

In case the list of `csv` files is so big that you get a *"argument list too long"* error.

You'd need a loop if you wanted to remove the header for all but the first file, but even, then you'd rather redirect the output of the loop than editing each file in place and concatenate later.

```
(
  rm -f combined.csv && set ./*.csv &&
  {
    cut -d, -f1-40 < "$1"
    shift
    for file do
      tail -n+2 < "$file" | cut -d, -f1-40
    done
  } > combined.csv
)
```

In any case, note that using `tail` and `cut` like that assumes csv cells don't contain `,` or newline characters. To be able to deal with csvs with arbitrary contents, you'd want to use proper csv manipulation utilities such as `mlr` or `csvtool` or proper programming languages such as `perl` or `python` and their csv modules.

Comment: Thank you @KamilMaciorowski. Would headers be repeated?

Comment: @Annabanana `cut` has no concept of a header, it processes lines. All lines will be processed, including these *you* call headers. `…; do tail -n +2 "$file" | cut -d ',' -f1-40; done …` will skip the first line from every file, including the first one.

Comment: So I would have to also do something like `tail -n+2` to get rid of the headers?

Comment: @Annabanana If my previous comment is not enough, consider asking another question (after searching, maybe it's already answered). Don't let this thread become [chameleon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/355310), even in comments.

Comment: Fair point. I edited my original question to make it more clear that I want to retain headers (without repeating them.) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your system/constraints allow it, consider a CSV-dedicated tool.  I like (and now maintain a fork of) [GoCSV](https://github.com/zacharysyoung/GoCSV).

Its **select** subcommand has a syntax and function very much like **cut**:

```bsh
for file in *.csv; do 
  gocsv select -c 1-40 $file > processed_$file
done
```

and then you can "stack" all the cut-down, processed CSVs together:

```bsh
gocsv stack processed_*.csv > combined.csv
```

Because GoCSV is aware of the CSV format and headers, you should get the result you're looking for with only a few lines of shell.

**stack** also has its **-filenames** option which adds the filename to a special grouping column, so you can reference any row back to its original file (and pretty-print w/**viewmd**):

```bsh
gocsv stack --filenames processed_*.csv | gocsv viewmd

| foo | File                |
|-----|---------------------|
| 1   | processed_file1.csv |
| 2   | processed_file1.csv |
| 3   | processed_file2.csv |
| 4   | processed_file2.csv |
```